# discord.py возможность писать команду только определенным людям

Tags: discord.py

**В формате ['user#0001', 'discord#0000']**

Comment: А в чём вопрос и ли проблема, собственно?

Answer (score 2):

Пожалуйста, прилагайте свой код или задавайте конкретный вопрос в следующий раз.

Ограничить использование для определённых пользователей можно так:

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):

    user_list = ["name#1111", "name2#1234"]  #список пользователей
    user = f"{ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}"  #взять id и ник юзера

    if user in user_list:
        await ctx.send("Всё получилось.")
    else:
        await ctx.send("У вас нет разрешения.")
```

Comment: Если мой ответ решит Вашу проблему, пожалуйста, поставьте галочку, тем самым указав, что вопрос решён.